# Highcharts area: x-axis in hours but showing multiple points in each hour

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/area-basic/) from highcharts but I need to adjust it as follows:

1. having the x-axis displaying the current 24 hours starting from current hour (I was able to draw the 24 hrs but not from current hour)

   ```
    xAxis: {
               type: 'datetime',
               tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
               min: Date.UTC(2013,4,22),
               max: Date.UTC(2013,4,23),
           },
   ```
2. displaying multiple points between 2 consecutive hours

any ideas?

Here is the full code of the jsfiddle:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
            'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            pointStart: 1940,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius: 2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'USA',
        data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
            1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
            27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
            26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
            24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
            22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
            10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104]
    }, {
        name: 'USSR/Russia',
        data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
            5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
            4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
            15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
            33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
            35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
            21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
    }]
});
```

});

Comment: I am not sure I understand your second requirement "displaying multiple points between 2 consecutive hours". If you want to display data for arbitrary time spans then a full time-based series would be best and not use an interval approach.

Comment: so what's the actual question/problem? You can set your axis tickInterval to whatever you want, and display points at whatever interval you want as well, and I am not seeing an actual question to clarify what part of it you are having trouble with

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some javascript and a change to a highcharts global options. Here is the code to get the current time:

```
var now = new Date();
var utc_timestamp = now.getTime();
var startTime = utc_timestamp;
var endTime = utc_timestamp + 86400000; // add 24 hours (in millis).

console.log(startTime);
console.log(endTime);
```

This will return a UTC time. Now to get the chart to use the user's local time set the [`useUTC`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC) parameter to:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

So your `xAxis` looks like:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
  min: startTime,
  max: endTime
},
```

Here is functional but basic **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/tyzuobo4/)**. Note that you also have to change the `plotOptions.series.pointStart` and `.pointInterval`. And note that the series have more than 24 points.